# Flutter Web: How to get query params from service worker?

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web

I have a native website (e.g. blabla.com) and I'm passing data with query parameters to a flutter website. Params not showing in link. But I can see in devtool my data.

[image]

[image]

My question is; how can I get data from service worker.
Thanks...

Comment: try this maybe: `navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
  registrations.forEach(function(v) { console.log(v) });
});`

Comment: I will try, thanks friend.

Comment: Your suggestion brought a lot of data. But not my data... 

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to use. in web/index.html, I've created a function:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  const params = new Proxy(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search), {
    get: (searchParams, prop) => searchParams.get(prop),
   );

  function getEmail() {
    return params.email;
  }
</script>
```

and in the main.dart file, I imported dart:js package

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
```

and I call it that I've created javascript function in web/index.html

```
String? email;
  
Future<void> getEmail() async {
  setState(() {
    email = js.context.callMethod('getEmail');
  });
}
```

I added the codes above in case other people need it. thanks